# Adding an onclick event inside an object's constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, constructor, onclick, element

I have a class called CDialogOption. A dialog option is being created inside of a dialog box and has a name, an action and an html element. The action is an object that has an "execute" function which is supposed to be executed when the user clicks on the html element of the dialog option object. For testing purposes I have deactivated this.action.execute() and replaced it with console.log("It works!")
Here's the code:

```
class CDialogOption extends CUIObject
   {
   constructor(_name, _dialogBoxName, _action)
   {
      super(_name);
      this.action = _action;
      this.dialogBoxName = _dialogBoxName;
      this.element = $('<div />', {class: 'dialogOption UIObject', id: this.name}).text(this.action.name).appendTo("#"+this.dialogBoxName);
      this.element.onclick = function ()
      {
         console.log("It works!");
         //this.action.execute();
      };
   }
}
```

My problem right now is, that nothing happens when I click on the element. I know that there are multiple posts and tutorials on the internet explaining how to add an onclick event using javascript and I tried to replicate it inside of this constructor but it didn't work for me. Maybe you could explain to me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.element is a jQuery object.

So try

```
this.element.on("click",function()  {
  console.log("It works!");
});
```

Alternatives:

```js
const div = $('<div />', {
    class: 'dialogOption UIObject',
    id: "Name"
  })
  .on("click",() => { console.log("from jQuery one") })
  .text("action")
  .appendTo("#x");
  
div[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('it works')
});
div.on("click",() => { console.log("from jQuery too") })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this.element contain a jquery object not a DOM object.

You should :

```
this.element.click(function ()
{
    console.log("It works!");
    //this.action.execute();
});
```